# How can orders be changed using the Shopify API?

Tags: shopify

Shopify Gurus! I'd like to know if any one of these is possible:

- Step in at the checkout process and submit some user input for validation using a 3rd-party API
- Submit certain details of an order to that same 3rd-party API for validation from the management panel (for instance, as the store takes the order to begin processing it)

The validation results in either case will need to replace the user's original input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No to both.

Long answer:

1. Steps 1 and 2 of the checkout are a black box, no external content is allowed. Therefore you can't add extra stuff to either of those pages.
2. Post-checkout you can send details off to a third party for validation, but in general orders are immutable on Shopify. There are a couple of exceptions to this:

   - Status: You can update the status of the order through the API
   - Order Notes: You can add notes to the order through the API

   Neither of these options allow for the updating of customer info (shipping/billing addresses, payment information, etc.). You can however notify the merchant that the order is invalid for whatever reason and cancel it. This is most useful for fraud detection services.

Comment: Thanks. Guess I'll have to put the validation results in Order Notes.